# How do I stop a ytdl stream?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, ytdl

How do I stop a ytdl stream if someone types -skip or something like that? I start the stream like this :

```js
search(searchfor, opts, function(err, results) {
    var rasss = results[0].link;
    const streamOptions = { seek: 0, volume: 1 };
    var voiceChannel = msg.member.voiceChannel;
    voiceChannel.join().then(connection => {
        const stream = ytdl(rasss, { filter : 'audioonly' });
        const dispatcher = connection.playStream(stream, streamOptions);
```

Comment: No I can not, it is not a thing. I thought it was. Nothing works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do

```js
dispatcher.destroy()
```

To stop the song, then you can play the next song in the queue. To do this, however, you need to define dispatcher outside of your function as null so you can use the dispatcher variable everywhere.

```js
let dispatcher;
```

And when actually defining dispatcher,

```js
dispatcher = connection.playStream(strea, streamOptions); // remove the keyword "const"
```